# TypeScript set value in object field from object in object (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I have an interface

```
export interface Shelving {
  _id?: string,
  name: string,
  location: string,
  comment: string,
  catID: string,
  catName: string
}
```

From the service I'm taking data from the server

```
  fetch(): Observable<Shelving[]> {
    return this.http.get<Shelving[]>('api/shelving')
  }
```

Object from the server

```
{
  "_id": "5ec3edbab1565f5d671c201e",
  "name": "89",
  "comment": "",
  "catID": "",
  "catName": "5ec3ed79b1565f5d671c201c",
  "location": "5ec3eccef1d51c3a48bd722e",
  "__v": 0,
  "categoryName": [    <-------------- object
    {
      "_id": "5ec3ed79b1565f5d671c201c",
      "catName": "test category name",  <------------------ name I needed
      "comment": "",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "locationObj": [
    {
      "_id": "5ec3eccef1d51c3a48bd722e",
      "name": "yyy",
      "phone": "+2310232309",
      "comment": "",
      "address": "EGNATIA 156",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The question is:
**How I can push the category name from object to array?** 
I want to print a value in html component. Something like this:
{{ shelving.catName }}
But now I'm printing like this:

```
<td>{{ shelving.categoryName[0].catName }}</td>
```

I thing it's not a true way -_-

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question. I can tell you one way to get that value out on to the template, if that's what you want:

```
catNames$: Observable<Shelving[]> = this.http.get<Shelving[]>('api/shelving').pipe(
          map(({ categoryName }) => categoryName.map(cat => cat.catName)),
          shareReplay(1)
       );
```

On html:

```
<td>{{ catNames$ | async }}</td>
```

All this does is map the values coming from the server into the shape you want, and then binds those values to the template through the `async` pipe. The `shareReplay(1)` is there to make sure the http endpoint doesn't get hit every time change detection runs.

One caveat here is you'll have to add `categoryName` as a property on your `Shelving` interface.